# error there is no package called 'codetools'

Tags: r, publishing, shiny

I'm trying to publish my ioslides_presentation to shyniapps.io but getting an error: **error there is no package called 'codetools'**.

The package is installed on the local machine. What is the problem? I use macOS Sierra, R version 3.2.2, RStudio version 1.0.44.

Comment: You'll have better luck asking this question on the [shinyapps.io mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shinyapps-users).

Comment: Are you explicitly loading it (somewhere in your shiny app/package) with `library`, or are you accessing it via some other method? The ShinyApps docs [chapter 2.4](http://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/getting-started.html#using-your-r-packages-in-the-cloud) lists that it should be auto-found when done in that fashion. (Realize that this problem is all about shinyapps.io and not about the version on your local machine.)

Comment: How were you referencing it? Using codetools::?

Comment: after contacting to shinyapps.io mailing list I got a suggestion to add 
library(codetools) to my setup section. 

knitr uses this package implicitly, but somehow didn't load it. Now it works.

Thanks for you suggestions.

Comment: @YevgenRyeznik You may post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am running R-Studio Server.  I received the same error when attempting to knit the file.

Loading the 'codetools' directly through R/R-Studio or on unix solved the issue for me.

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('codetools', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```